# Firedac Empty Result Set

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am sure that I'm overlooking some simple thing here.

With a FireDac connection, if I use a SQL query with a `WHERE` clause that, due to the content of the search parameter, would normally return an empty result set, the OPEN command returns an error instead "Cannot open / define command, which does not return result sets". Is this by design ? Every other Delphi DB connection tool I have used simply returns an empty result set with a record count of 0.

******************************* April 16
I believe Victoria is on the right track. I had never used Firedac before so assumed it was the behaviour as designed. However if I communicate with the same RDBMS using the MS SQL driver, I do not see this happen, so I suspect it is on the Datasnap end.

Comment: That should not happen. Try to create minimal example with your exact case and include information about the used DBMS and driver if you want to get accurate answer.

Comment: sure and thanks.  Lets say you have a table with a field called "color" and the only data is "red". You write a query        "SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE color = "Blue" .When you use Open their is no result set, only the error indicated above. The database is MS SQL and the the driver is DS (DataSnap)

Comment: That's crucial information. Try to reproduce that with a native SQL Server ODBC driver with direct connection to the DBMS. After that start blaming DataSnap (I bet the problem is there because official MS ODBC drivers can properly describe dataset even with empty resultset).

Comment: @Victoria is quite right that this should not happen.  Not only that, but it **does not** happen with the vast majority of Sql queries using FireDAC, otherwise SO and elsewhere would be awash with problem reports.  The fact that it happens for you means that it must be because of some detail you are not telling us in your q.

Please edit your q to add at the very minimum these details of your set-up[cont]

Comment: [cont] 1) Delphi version; 2) back-end RDMS and version; 3) FireDAC dataset type; 4) client-side driver used with the FD dataset; 5) DDL Sql to create the table on the server; 6) Sql INSERT statement to insert a single row in the table; and 7) the EXACT Delphi code you are using to open the table and which provokes the error you describe.  If you do not supply this info, I think your q should be closed because no-one will likely be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartynA, one might work with a statement results without dataset description, but that's not what happens with (at least) default FireDAC query object settings. Hence I would blame DataSnap :)

Comment: @Victoria:  I suppose it depends what one omeans by DataSnap, but I'm not too clear how modern DataSnap (as in Rest services, etc) would be involved in a simple FireDAC query.  I can't see any DataSnap dependencies in FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.PAS, for example, so perhaps I'm missing your point.

Comment: Re your edit, why do you assume that DataSnap is involved?

Comment: @MartynA, by describing dataset object I meant the common ability of the drivers to describe returned dataset (describe the fields so FireDAC can create and bind field collection for fetching resultset). And FireDAC shipps with DataSnap driver. But with this question as asked right now it's hard to guess the configuration.

Comment: @Victoria:  I thought I'd try the ko-fi.com thing but I got an error message "The Creator Didn't Give Payment Information" :(  I assume it's talking about you rather than some divine being, maybe it needs your paypal details or smth?

Comment: @MartynA, oh, I missed that point. I'll fix that soon (need to setup PayPal). I've added that for fun, but thank you very much for noticing that!